# Chrome extension not working after chrome update to Version 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit)

Tags: google-chrome-extension

After recent update of chrome browser to Version 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit)
my extension stopped working.Following is the explanation of the working on extension:

- **Popup.js**

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
      d = document;
      var f = d.createElement('form');
      f.action = 'https://example.com/login';
      f.method = 'post';
      var i = d.createElement('input');
      i.type = 'hidden';
      i.name = 'url';
      i.value = tab.url;
      console.log(tab.url);
      f.appendChild(i);
      d.body.appendChild(f);
      f.submit();
    });
});
```

- **popup.html**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    .image {
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto 
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body style="width: 350px;height:340px;">
    
    <h3>Connecting to server please wait ...</h3>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <img src="/loader.gif" alt="Please Wait" class="image" align="middle">
  </body>
</html>
```

- **manifest.json**

```js
{
"update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "test name",
  "description": "test description",
  "version": "0.1.2",

  "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "128.png",
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "icons": { 
      "16": "128.png",
      "32": "128.png",
      "64": "128.png",
      "128": "128.png" 
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  
  "web_accessible_resources": [ "128.png" ],

  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
   ]
}
```

Before the chrome update, extension was working fine.
 
- I am submitting a form with post method. 
- I am sending a key 'url' which I am checking on server site if the request is from extension and thus loading login form for extension.
 - Once the extension login loads into the popup, user logs in and is redirected to appropriate page within the popup. 
This is the flow of extension. But after the update, Loading continues on popup. The form submit request is being cancelled by the browser. On googling about the problem, I found using ajax post method for submitting the form instead of direct form submit. This method was able to fetch the login form from but that without any css and js of the webpage as the urls were relative in the page and chrome extension id was prepended as the base url with all the links. So, I changed those urls to absolute but the submit functionality was not working again as it was again a form. Again I changed the form submit into ajax post submit request on server side. But the javascript written over the webpage is not working in chrome extension. 
So question is how to make the extension work which was working earlier?

Comment: What is your actual question? You have a bunch of statements, but no question. Is *Pop.js* supposed to be *popup.js*? Please don't post partially minimized code. Please use variable names that are more than one character and that describe what the variable represents. Doing so makes your code more understandable to other people. When asking a question of people who are *volunteering their time*, don't make it harder for them to help you. Doing so results in fewer people being willing to help you.

Comment: Chrome 57 enabled *Site Isolation for extensions* which means you can't submit forms directly (which is a bad solution inside an extension anyway). Instead add an event listener for `submit` and `POST` via XHR, there are many examples.

Answer (score 0):

`chrome.tabs.getSelected()` is deprecated since Chrome 33. try using `chrome.tabs.query({ active: true })` like this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true }, function(tabs) {
      var tab = tabs[ 0 ];
      d = document;
      var f = d.createElement('form');
      f.action = 'https://example.com/login';
      f.method = 'post';
      var i = d.createElement('input');
      i.type = 'hidden';
      i.name = 'url';
      i.value = tab.url;
      console.log(tab.url);
      f.appendChild(i);
      d.body.appendChild(f);
      f.submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: Used chrome.tabs.query({ active: true }) but still faced same problem

Answer (score 0):

I've been encountering an issue where the DOMContentLoaded event appears to fire before the DOM is fully rendered. This has been an issue since my Chrome updated to 57.0.2987.133.

Perhaps you could use the window load event instead.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
```